# Is there a way to bookmark a YouTube links with low quality setting in the url?

Tags: bookmarks, youtube, url

I want to bookmark podcasts that are 2 hours long. I don't care for it to play in 1080p is there a way to have in the url that this video plays in 144p?

That way whenever I load it from bookmark it always loads at 144p and not waste data.

I've tried the vq parameter but it does not work.

```
default|none: vq=auto;
Code for auto: vq=auto;
Code for 2160p: vq=hd2160;
Code for 1440p: vq=hd1440;
Code for 1080p: vq=hd1080;
Code for 720p: vq=hd720;
Code for 480p: vq=large;
Code for 360p: vq=medium;
Code for 240p: vq=small;
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdClq1wiTsI&vq=small

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the vq still exists for embed link 
so this link https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZdClq1wiTsI/vq=small is currenly working and the quality is very low .